# How to detect which the first Makefile in a include chain?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have a directory `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/` and a file `Makefile` in that directory with the contents

```make
include ../Makefile
```

`~/dir1/dir2/Makefile` has the same contents as `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile`

If I am allowed to control the contents of `~/dir1/Makefile`, and `make` was invoked in `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/`, How do I get the string `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile`(The first include file) for use as a variable in `~/dir1/Makefile`?

Reproducible Example (as requested by MadScientist) :

1. Any unix system
2. `mkdir -p ~/dir1/dir2/dir3`
3. `cd ~/dir1/dir2/dir3`
4. `echo 'include ../Makefile' > Makefile`
5. `cp ./Makefile ../Makefile`

Now we have a Makefile in `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/` and `~/dir1/dir2/` with the same declaration, i.e. an include declaration that includes the Makefile in the parent directory.

If `make` is invoked in `~/dir1/dir2/dir3`, then the include chains finally stop at `~/dir1/Makefile`

How do I find the path of the first file in this chain of includes, i.e. `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile` for use as a variable in `~/dir1/Makefile`?

Comment: It would be easier to understand the question if the names of the directories weren't all the same.  I'm not sure how you get from `~/test/test/test/Makefile` to `~/test/Makefile`... is there another include?  In any event, I think you can get what you are looking for by appropriate use of `MAKEFILE_LIST` https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029 but if not maybe you can clarify the question, hopefully with a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would suggest that you use `include` only to incorporate makefile fragments that are specifically designed for and used exclusively for that purpose.  Otherwise, use recursive `make` if you want to use rules defined in other makefiles.  This will save you a lot of headaches.  Among those is being uncertain of whether any given file is the root of the inclusion tree.

Comment: @MadScientist I have refactored the post as per your proposal. `MAKEFILE_LIST` indeed does the job for me, but after refactoring the post I have discovered another error. Somehow, including an Makefile from a parent directory means that you cannot include another Makefile present in the parent directory of the included Makefile(in the included Makefile), the example I've cooked up returns a Bad Address error in make due to the dir2 makefile including ```../Makefile```

Comment: Your newly discovered error is a bug in the lower two makefiles; you can fix it, but not from within the top makefile. As for the primary problem, do you want the tilde ('~')? An absolute path (e.g. `/users/monke/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile`) is much easier to construct.

Answer (score 1):

**To get the full path of the first make file invoked from the CLI:**

```
make_path_called_from_cli:=$(firstword $(foreach mk,${MAKEFILE_LIST},$(abspath ${mk})))
```

**To get the full path of the make file which included the current make file:**

```
$(info Using GNUmake Special variable to obtain Every make file used...)

$(info ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

$(info Compute the full path for all of those make files...)
all_make_file_full_path:=$(foreach mk,${MAKEFILE_LIST},$(abspath ${mk}))

$(info ${all_make_file_full_path})

$(info The last one from the list is the current make file...)

current_make_file_path:=$(lastword ${all_make_file_full_path})
$(info ${current_make_file_path})

$(info Now we remove the current make file from the list of make...)
all_make_file_path_except_current:=$(filter-out ${current_make_file_path}, ${all_make_file_full_path})

$(info ${all_make_file_path_except_current})

# Now the last one from the list is the make file which included the current one
parent_make_file_path:=$(lastword ${all_make_file_path_except_current})

$(info We finally have the answer...)
$(info ${parent_make_file_path})
```

Comment: I believe OP was asking for the first makefile invoked (the one from the command line), which would simply be `$(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))`